# password management

Tags: java, encryption, passwords, password-encryption

I have a question about password management.
Let's suppose I have a program and the user enter a password, and the data is stored encrypted.

One way would be:
Encrypt data with the user's password.
pros: the user would take charge of the security of the password and how secure your data.
Cons: If the user changes the password must decrypt and encrypt all data.

otherwise:
Data is encrypted with a password other than the user (random). And the user password used to encrypt the random password.
Pros: If the user changes the password does not have to re-encrypt everything.

And as for save the user's password, I' am  using to jasypt.org. Is it okay? What would be the correct way to do it?
I think the weak point is in the encryptor Jasypt.
The data with  encrypted AES-128. 
Use Jasypt because that's all I know.

Comment: Jasypt in general *seems* to keep to well established cryptographic standards, yes. Won't make this an additional answer, as I cannot vouch for the library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you should encrypt a *data key* with the password.

To encrypt, the password would be converted to a key first. You would use a password based key derivation function for that (PBKDF). PBKDF2 is currently the most standard option for that.

You encrypt the data with a randomly generated key. This key is in turn encrypted with the key generated from the password.

To change the password, ask for the original first. Then decrypt the data key. You may then ask for a new password and re-encrypt the data key. The encrypted data itself does not have to be touched.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you want to use `salted password hashing`.  [CrackStation](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) has a very good article on the subject.

Comment: Interesting article you are pointing to, but that's only half of the question you've answered.

Comment: @owlstead UR correct, I briefly read question and thouhgt it was about storing the password!  +1 to you.